# how to read from this JSON in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

Say I have a JSON like this:

```
{
    "99999":{
            "success":true,
            "data":{
                "type":"blob",
                "name":"random"
            }
        }
}
```

How do I access the "name", where the "99999" will be different each time?

Comment: something like `data[x].data.name`

Comment: How do you know what the key (ie. the `99999` value in your example) will be? Or do you just want to access the first property of the object?

Comment: Thanks levi, data[x].data.name did it

Comment: @NaughtySquid did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 4):

you can use below code with JSON.parse.

```
 var jsondata = '{"99999":{"success":true,"data":
         {"type":"blob","name":"random"}}}';

 $.each(JSON.parse(jsondata), function(idx, obj) {
  console.log(obj.data.name);
 });
```

Comment: "name" is a keyword, and while it works here, you could more safely use obj.data['name'].

Comment: thanks,@KatharineOsborne obj.data['name'] but it is not working here.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your callback function (json is the json object not a string) :

```
function(json){
  $.each(json,function(index,val){
     var success=val.success;
     var name=val.data.name;
     //index = 99999 in your example
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using JavaScript :**

```js
var jsonObj = {
    "99999":{
            "success":true,
            "data":{
                "type":"blob",
                "name":"random"
            }
        }
};

var result = Object.keys(jsonObj).map(item => {return jsonObj[item].data.name});

console.log(result[0]);
```

**Using jQuery :**

```js
var jsonObj = {
    "99999":{
            "success":true,
            "data":{
                "type":"blob",
                "name":"random"
            }
        }
};

$.each(jsonObj, function(index, obj) {
  console.log(obj.data.name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```